# Why didn't the answerer get my bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I had asked the question "[How can I bind or otherwise get & set a value of a control in a resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163447/how-can-i-bind-or-otherwise-get-set-a-value-of-a-control-in-a-resource)". As I considered it a difficult question to answer, I promised that I would award a +50 bounty to the person who answered it.

As the system required me to wait 2 days to award a bounty, even though the answer was written the same day, I patiently waited till the 2 days were up, placed the bounty and then selected the correct answer. I thought that would reward the person who helped me with the bounty. I even got a message in my inbox saying

> Your bounty on question "How can I bind or otherwise get & set a value of a control in a resource?" is completed and will be auto-awarded in 24 hours".

But, it appears that the bounty did not get auto-awarded. The answerer says that he didn't receive it.

How can I find out if he got the bounty? If he didn't get it, how can I find out who got it (there was one other answer, but I didn't select it as the correct answer)? Is there a way to correct it?:(

Comment: The auto-award works only for answers that are added *after* the bounty was placed, it's like a last resort when the bounty owner doesn't return to the site in time. You should have given it to the answer of your choice proactively, instead of waiting for the system to auto-award. If you want, I can start a new one and give it to them

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand how the bounty system worked. I will award it on another question that the person answered, just to make the reward. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The auto-award is only half the usual award, so there's **never** a reason to wait for the system to do it if you're willing to accept a given answer as the bounty winner.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If the user accepts a (new?) answer during the bounty period it will auto award the full amount. Only if it auto accepts an unaccepted answer will it be half the amount.

Comment: @Nathan, I wouldn't say never. Someone can post a better answer during the period. And you can let the others see the question with an active bounty which in turn can bring some votes.

Comment: We'll get some bounty points to that answer, no worry.

Comment: @TLama: Right; you don't necessarily want to award the bounty *before the period ends*, but you do want to award it *before the end of the grace period*, to keep the system from choosing one automatically.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I didn't actually intend for it to auto-awarded. At the time, I thought that selecting an answer as the correct one while the bounty was active was the way to assign the bounty. I didn't realize that I had to click on the +50. I hadn't logged into SO for 2 days while the bounty was expiring, so I hadn't seen the system message in time that the bounty would be auto-awarded in 24 hours. After seeing the message, I was still confused, as I thought it meant that the bounty was already auto-awarded.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to click the "little blue button" of bounty, below the "Accept answer" green tick, to give explicitly the bounty to the person who you consider most helpful. One step more, I think, for confirmation reason. Try not to miss this step. Tricky, at first moment.

The auto-reward is the half of the real bounty.